# Autonomous Vehicle software commercial platform

Tags: autonomy

I am looking for autonomous software for my research project. I know some open-source software like Apollo and Autoware but I would like to know more about full self-driving commercial software. Do companies like Waymo, Cruise, and Tesla sell their AV software stacks? Does anyone have some suggestions? I mean a full platform, not just a few ADAS functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

**Before You choose a simulator, You must define your project's requirements.** Some of the requirements are:

1. Do You want to visualize your simulation? Are high quality graphics important for your project?
2. Are you going to use Sensors to collect data from your environment or your project takes a more theoretical approach?
3. In what language are You going to write your code? Also, in which platform you are going to run your simulator?

Anyway, there are a lot of AV simulators out there. Personally, My favourite is **Carla** simulator:

https://carla.org/

However, If you are a researcher You can also download NVIDIA Drive Sim. This one is also used by many automotive industries:

https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/self-driving-cars/simulation/

Also, many papers about Autonomous Vehicles use Eclipse SUMO to test their algorithms:

https://www.eclipse.org/sumo/

You can check all of them and see which one of those covers your project requirements.